# How to add multiple navbars in flask?

Tags: python, flask

I have a primary navigation and now I want to add a secondary navigation within a view. Kind of like stackoverflow has [interesting, bounty, hot, week, month].

I have tried this but get internal server errors. How do I implement this in my blueprint properly?

My blueprint:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, redirect, url_for, flash
from flask import current_app as app
from flask_login import login_required

myView_bp = Blueprint(
    'myView_bp', __name__,
    template_folder='templates',
    static_folder='static'
)

@myView_bp.route('/myView', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def myView():
    nav.context.Item('interesting', 'interesting_bp.interestingStuff')
    nav.context.Item('bounty', 'bounty_bp.bountyStuff')
    nav.context.Item('hot', 'hot_bp.hotStuff')
    return render_template('myView.html')
```

My application init:

```
...
from flask_navigation import Navigation

...

def create_app(config_class=Config):

    ...

    nav = Navigation(app)
    nav.init_app(app)
    nav.Bar('top', [
        nav.Item('Home', 'home_bp.home'),
        nav.Item('profile', 'profile_bp.testPage'),
        nav.Item('new', 'new_bp.analyzePage'),
    ])
    nav.Bar('context')
    
    with app.app_context():
        ...
        return app
```

Comment: [According to the docs](https://flask-navigation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) FlaskNavigation utilizes jinja template rendering and app context-bound variables to store the navigation bar structure. jinja will then access this variable and render the elements into the HTML. I have never used FlaskNavigation, but I think that you could add a second navbar quite similar to the first one (as it basically just adds a variable to the app context which will be accessed by jinja upon rendering).

Comment: Yes, I believe that's what I've attempted. So I'm not sure what I've done wrong.